# Replace the value

Tags: plsql

We have column 'a' in 'X' and 'Y' table. If value of column 'a' is not null then we need to consider in 'X' table otherwise need to consider in 'Y' table.

Based on this requirement how to achieve it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Consider table as in SELECT / UDPATE / INSERT. where? Please send code where you are trying to achieve this.

Comment: You need to provide more information for an answer. Post your table structure with sample data. Also, please be more specific technically in what you want to do. Do you need a SELECT query that fetches from Y if data is not available in X?

Comment: Can the two tables be joined?

Comment: @SantoshAradya did my answer work for you?  If not can you provide some more information?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're asking about the [NVL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions119.htm#SQLRF00684) function.  Based on the limited information to go on hopefully this will work for you...

```
CREATE TABLE x(id int, a varchar(255));
INSERT INTO x(id, a) VALUES(1, 'One');
INSERT INTO x(id, a) VALUES(2, null);
INSERT INTO x(id, a) VALUES(3, 'Three');

CREATE TABLE y(id int, a varchar(255));
INSERT INTO y(id, a) VALUES(1, 'One');
INSERT INTO y(id, a) VALUES(2, 'Two');
INSERT INTO y(id, a) VALUES(3, 'Three');

select x.id, nvl(x.a,y.a) a
from x, y
where x.id = y.id;
```

Results in...

```
ID  a
==========
1   One
2   Two
3   Three
```